# How to make a universal function that will give weight to elements depending on their characteristics?

Tags: algorithm, go, math

I try to write function which calculate weigh of element depends of transferFee and distance values of element.
Example:
if fuelPercent is 95, function must give object with ID 2, because less fee is more matter than less distance. But if fuelPercent is 81 function must give object with ID 1 because for this case less fee is less matter than less distance.

But I have problem, whatever ratio I put, algorithm always chose element with ID 1.

I understand that the problem is due to multiplications, but I don't understand how to fix this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type PlanetInfo struct {
    ID          int
    TransferFee float64
    Distance    float64
    Weight      float64
}

func main() {
    fuelPercent := 95.
    engines := make([]PlanetInfo, 0)
    engines = append(engines, PlanetInfo{
        ID:          1,
        TransferFee: 7.5,
        Distance:    96,
    })
    engines = append(engines, PlanetInfo{
        ID:          2,
        TransferFee: 6,
        Distance:    65,
    })

    feeRatio := 0.
    distanceRatio := 0.
    switch {
    case fuelPercent > 90:
        feeRatio = 0.9
        distanceRatio = 0.1
    case fuelPercent >= 85 && fuelPercent < 90:
        feeRatio = 0.8
        distanceRatio = 0.2
    case fuelPercent >= 80 && fuelPercent < 85:
        feeRatio = 0.6
        distanceRatio = 0.4
    case fuelPercent < 80:
        feeRatio = 0.1
        distanceRatio = 0.9
    }

    fmt.Printf("distanceRatio: %f\n", distanceRatio)
    fmt.Printf("feeRation: %f\n", feeRatio)

    for i, r := range engines {
        fmt.Printf("%d; distanceRatio; %f * %f = %f\n", r.ID, r.Distance, distanceRatio, r.Distance*distanceRatio)
        fmt.Printf("%d; feeRation; %f * %f = %f\n", r.ID, r.TransferFee, feeRatio, r.TransferFee*feeRatio)
        fmt.Printf("%f * %f + %f + %f = %f\n", feeRatio, r.Distance, distanceRatio, r.TransferFee, feeRatio*r.TransferFee+distanceRatio*r.Distance)
        engines[i].Weight = r.TransferFee*feeRatio + r.Distance*distanceRatio
    }

    sort.Slice(engines, func(i, j int) bool {
        return engines[i].Weight > engines[j].Weight
    })

    PrintStructJSON(engines) // always give first element
}

func PrintStructJSON(value interface{}) {
    result, err := json.MarshalIndent(value, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n" + string(result) + "\n")
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DYK71i1A_f8)

Comment: Please add language tag

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your original code was the logic that calculated the weight of the elements. Simply multiplying the transfer fee and distance by their respective ratios and adding the results would not provide the desired prioritization because it was just scaling the values of transfer fee and distance, but was not effectively capturing the relative importance of one over the other.

A revised approach would be to first [normalize these factors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13638464/6309) (transfer fee and distance) by dividing each value by the maximum value in the set. That brings both factors into the same scale, between 0 and 1.

Next, we multiply each normalized value by its respective weight ratio, determined by the `fuelPercent`. That gives greater importance to either the transfer fee or distance, based on the `fuelPercent` value. A higher `fuelPercent` gives more weight to the transfer fee, while a lower `fuelPercent` gives more weight to the distance.

Finally, we add these weighted, normalized values together to get a final 'weight' for each option. That weight effectively combines both the transfer fee and distance into a single value that can be used to compare options.

Now, a lower weight represents a better option - i.e., one with a lower transfer fee and/or shorter distance. The options can be sorted by this weight, giving a list where the most optimal choice (given the current `fuelPercent`) is first.

Here is the revised weight calculation ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HYJw6qvkOtE)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type PlanetInfo struct {
    ID          int
    TransferFee float64
    Distance    float64
    Weight      float64
}

func main() {
    fuelPercent := 95.
    engines := make([]PlanetInfo, 0)
    engines = append(engines, PlanetInfo{
        ID:          1,
        TransferFee: 7.5,
        Distance:    96,
    })
    engines = append(engines, PlanetInfo{
        ID:          2,
        TransferFee: 6,
        Distance:    65,
    })

    feeRatio := 0.
    distanceRatio := 0.
    switch {
    case fuelPercent > 90:
        feeRatio = 0.9
        distanceRatio = 0.1
    case fuelPercent >= 85 && fuelPercent < 90:
        feeRatio = 0.8
        distanceRatio = 0.2
    case fuelPercent >= 80 && fuelPercent < 85:
        feeRatio = 0.6
        distanceRatio = 0.4
    case fuelPercent < 80:
        feeRatio = 0.1
        distanceRatio = 0.9
    }

    fmt.Printf("distanceRatio: %f\n", distanceRatio)
    fmt.Printf("feeRatio: %f\n", feeRatio)

    maxDistance := 0.0
    maxTransferFee := 0.0
    for _, r := range engines {
        if r.Distance > maxDistance {
            maxDistance = r.Distance
        }
        if r.TransferFee > maxTransferFee {
            maxTransferFee = r.TransferFee
        }
    }

    for i, r := range engines {
        weightedDistance := (r.Distance / maxDistance) * distanceRatio
        weightedFee := (r.TransferFee / maxTransferFee) * feeRatio
        engines[i].Weight = weightedDistance + weightedFee
        fmt.Printf("%d; weightedDistance: %f\n", r.ID, weightedDistance)
        fmt.Printf("%d; weightedFee: %f\n", r.ID, weightedFee)
        fmt.Printf("%d; Weight: %f\n", r.ID, engines[i].Weight)
    }

    sort.Slice(engines, func(i, j int) bool {
        return engines[i].Weight < engines[j].Weight
    })

    PrintStructJSON(engines)
}

func PrintStructJSON(value interface{}) {
    result, err := json.MarshalIndent(value, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n" + string(result) + "\n")
}
```

You get:

```
distanceRatio: 0.100000
feeRatio: 0.900000
1; weightedDistance: 0.100000
1; weightedFee: 0.900000
1; Weight: 1.000000
2; weightedDistance: 0.067708
2; weightedFee: 0.720000
2; Weight: 0.787708

[
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "TransferFee": 6,
        "Distance": 65,
        "Weight": 0.7877083333333335
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "TransferFee": 7.5,
        "Distance": 96,
        "Weight": 1
    }
]
```

`ID 2` comes first now.